# Windows 7 recording only has sound from 1 channel

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, audio-recording

I have a mic that is (naturally) mono. It is connected to my Windows 7 PC via the mic input (3.5mm). The plug is mono (2 segment). When I hear my recording, sound come out from 1 side of the speakers only.

It seems all the recording option (from Windows's Sound Control Panel) is 2-channels. Is there a way to let Windows know that my mic is not stereo? I suppose I can use software to change the recorded audio to 2 channels but I am using this mic for Skype. Or should I use an adapter to convert mono to stereo? I am concerned that doing so will affect audio quality.

Comment: This sounds normal. If you are recording a stereo file you are only going to hear audio from one channel. Change to a mono file and it should be fine. Typically a mono signal is recorded on the right-channel. Why do you think Skype is going to have a problem? Have you tried it?

Comment: A mono-to-stereo adapter should be fine, not changing sound quality. There are also virtual audio devices that might send mono to both input channels. See https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/vban.htm , though I've not used it for that purpose.

Comment: I think if I use mono-to-stereo adapter, it will effectively reduce the volume by half and double the noise? I am kind of puzzled since almost all "stick" mics I've seen are mono. I thought there is a simple way to specify that I'm using a single channel recording device but I was wrong.